# Next Move on this Sudoku Classic

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, sudoku

What would be the next move?

[Link to this sudoku](https://f-puzzles.com/?id=yzh8jxnv)

[image]

Comment: There are online solvers that go through step by step using methods that humans can do...

Comment: You have a 237 triple in box 6. That lets you place the 6 in box 6.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Check out our [tour]. Note that you can upvote and/or "accept" my answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 3):

First, let's list all the possibilities for the 3x3 box in the middle of the left edge:

> [image: possibilities listed]

Now, for the deductions:

> Observed the four green cells. In all these cells, only (1, 5, 8, 9) are the possible numbers. Since there are four green cells and four numbers to share, each cell will have one of (1, 5, 8, 9). Therefore no other cell in this box can use any of (1, 5, 8, 9). We can remove those numbers from each other cell's candidates.

That gives us:

> [image: possibilities removed]

It should now be clear that:

> R4C8 must be 6, there are no other possibilities.

Hopefully that's enough for a "next move"

Disclaimer: I did not figure this out myself, but used [this sudoku solver](https://www.sudokuwiki.org/sudoku.htm) to point me in the right direction. Images made with [Penpa+](https://swaroopg92.github.io/penpa-edit/)

Comment: Same logic, but a bit more simply: there are two sets of 237 looking at box 6, creating a 237 triple, which is enough to place the six.